# react-native-google-signIn not getting IDToken

Tags: android, react-native

We are using react-native-google-signIn for android in our project. We have created a project in google developer console and downloaded the google-services.json file. The google-services.json file is placed in android/apps folder.

When we configure the googleSignIn in code , am getting error: 10 code from google.

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
       webClientId:'***********************.apps.googleusercontent.com'
})
```

If i don't pass the `webClientId` , the sign-in is successful but `idToken` is returned as null in the user object.

I made sure that the `webClientId` value is correct by following [[1]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin) and [[2]](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/issues/263).

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SHA-1 key may be incorrect. The comment of @mtt87 did help me:

https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/issues/224

Comment: Thanks for the link. Have one more doubt. Should my development android environment SHA1 key be updated in google develper console ? Another developer was working on this project sometime back. He has configured this project in google developer console.

Comment: And also how to update SHA-1 key in google developer console for already created project

Comment: @BhuvanaAbhisheg, you can add multiple SHA-1 keys to the project. The steps in the link it can be applied for both new and existed projects.

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using firebase and kept getting the same issue until I passed the web client_id from the firebase google-services file into the GoogleSignin.configure method.

```
await GoogleSignin.configure({
        webClientId: '<unique string>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      });
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

Comment: **Which** client Id? My file has 3 different `client_id` fields. None of them are labeled "web". They have client types 1, 2, 3. And why do we need to provide this? Isn't that the point of integrating the `google-services.json`?

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a problem related to SHA1 key.
Make sure you have placed both debug and release SHA1 key to your firebase project.

for finding SHA1 key:
go to your android folder and hit below command

For debug mode :

```
 keytool -keystore app/debug.keystore -list -v
```

For release mode:

```
keytool -keystore app/release.keystore -list -v
```